# How to cycle through htop search results

Tags: htop

In `htop` I can use `/` to search for terms, and typically when searching in tools like `less` and `vi`, I can use `n` or `N` to show the various instances of results that I find, but this doesn't work in `htop`. Does anyone know how to show next and previous results when searching in `htop`?

Thanks!

Comment: `htop` AFAIK is meant primarily for interactive use, but for this use-case I would suggest searching the output of `top -b -n1`.

Comment: The version I use ( 2.0.2 ) has <F3> for next result. You also could use the filter function <F4> to only show the results and navigate with up/down keys.

Comment: @Thomas - the filter is what I needed thanks. would be glad to accept as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use <kbd>F3</kbd> `Search` key  to go to next occurrence of the search item. This works regardless of whether you initiate the search with <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>. Just be sure to avoid pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> or else <kbd>F3</kbd> will start a new search instead of continuing the previous one.